# Problem in understanding a sentence

Tags: sentence, science

I am a native german speaker and I have a problem in understanding a question in an assignment which I have to solve.

What does this sentence mean:

"Plot the total consumption D over the interval I, upon convergence."

Does it mean, I have to plot the consumption until it converges or only the converged consumption?

Comment: It is unclear, and the precise meaning (if there is one) must be determined from the context.

Answer (score 1):

By saying "upon convergence", the assignment is asking for ***only the converged consumpution.***

I would disagree with those who say the sentence is unclear.

In this case, *upon* is synonymous with *at*.  In other words, "Once you get convergence, **then** plot the total consumption."

If the assignment had been requesting additional points leading up to convergence, it would say "Plot ... until convergence" or "Plot ... up to and including convergence."

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean, I have to plot the consumption until it converges or only the converged consumption?

Grammatically speaking, it is unclear (as Hot Licks already commented before me).

However, I would read from the context (which is an assumption, not a guarantee); that the examinator is only interested in the points of convergence.
My interpretation would be to plot the convergent points (and maybe any nearby points to provide a clearer image).